# Declaring an array of objects of a class when a (non) default constructor is (not) defined?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, default-constructor

Suppose I define a class in C++, MyClass, and want to create an array of 100 such objects, i.e. ArrayMyClass.

Before that, lets say I declare a single object of MyClass, i.e.

MyClass Obj;

Lets take the following cases:

1. MyClass has only a default constructor
2. MyClass has only a non-default constructor with no default parameters
3. MyClass has only a non-default constructor with default parameters
4. MyClass has both a default and non-default constructor, but the latter has no default parameters
5. MyClass has both a default and non-default constructor, but the latter has default parameters
6. MyClass has 2 non-default constructors, one of them has default and the other has no default parameters
7. MyClass has a default constructor, and two non-default constructors, one with default parameters and the other one doesn't have default parameters.
8. MyClass has no constructors defined.

I'm trying to figure out in which cases will the object get declared and which constructor gets invoked.

My understanding is that the type of parameters passed on the object decides which constructor gets invoked. So,

1. In case 1, object should get declared if no parameters are passed. If parameters are passed it should throw an error.
2. In case 2, object should get declared only if I pass the right type of parameters. It should throw an error if I don't pass any parameters or if I pass the wrong type/number of parameters.
3. Object should get declared, if I pass the right type/number of parameters, but also if I pass no parameters. It'll throw an error only if the type/number of parameters is incorrect.
4. If no parameters are passed, the default constructor gets invoked. If the right parameters are passed the non default constructor gets invoked.
5. In the case when I pass the right parameters, the non default constructor gets invoked. I'm confused what happens when you pass no parameters.
6. In this case, if I pass no parameters, the non default constructor with default parameters should get invoked. I'm not sure what happens when you pass parameters. Is it that a class cannot have 2 constructors with the same type/number of parameters?
7. This case looks similar to case 5 and I have the same confusion.
8. In this case, if no parameters are passed, I assume C++ provides a built in bare bones constructor. But if I pass parameters it should throw an error.

Suppose I declare an array of such objects, i.e.

MyClass ArrayMyClass[100];

For this declaration, from my understanding I've the same inferences for those 8 cases that I have with declaring just one object.

Is my understanding is incorrect anywhere? Also what happens in those cases which I couldn't figure out?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: If `MyClass` doesn't have a default constructor (a constructor that can be invoked with no arguments), then `MyClass Obj;` won't compile.

Comment: But it should compile if it has a non default constructor with default parameters, right?

Comment: A constructor that can be called with no arguments (whether because it has no parameters or because all parameters have defaults) is, by definition, a default constructor. In light of this, I'm not sure what you mean by *"non default constructor with default parameters"*

Comment: Anyway, if `MyClass Obj;` compiles, then `MyClass ArrayMyClass[100];` would also compile. The same constructor that gets called in the first case, will also get called in the second case, a hundred times.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik non default constructor with default parameters, would be a constructor where the variables that are passed as parameters in the class definition also have a default value defined in case values aren't passed while declaring an object. That's what I've learnt from the book (Abhiram Ranade) I'm using as reference.

Comment: for example, 
`MyClass (type var1 = 0, type var2 = 1) {
}`

is a non default constructor for a class with 2 data members, which has default parameters 0,1. 
Apparently if we just declare 
`MyClass obj1;`
This would give obj1 object with 0,1 as the values of its data members.

Comment: The constructor you show is in fact a default constructor. If your book says otherwise, get a better book. [This](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#class.default.ctor-1) is what the C++ standard has to say: "**[class.default.ctor]/1** A *default constructor* for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` for which each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a default argument (including the case of a constructor with no parameters)."

Comment: I disagree. The constructor I've shown above is a non default constructor (NDC). A DC doesn't take any parameters. If an NDC has default parameters, it will override those values if you pass specific parameter values while defining an object.

Comment: The C++ standard is an authoritative document that defines the C++ language.  The meaning of the term *"default constructor"* is what the standard says it is. The passage I quoted from the standard is very clear: a constructor with no parameters is one, but not the only one, possible case of a default constructor. This is not really open for discussion.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. Shouldn't rely on just one reference.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, a class can not have two constructors or functions with the same signature (same name and same number+type of parameters).

Case 1-4: Your assumption about case 1-4 is correct.

Case 5: Your first part of assumption about case 5 is also correct. As for your question about what happens when you pass no parameters, you will get "Call of overloaded YOURCLASSNAME() is ambiguous. Take a look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box {
    public:
    int height, width, depth;
    Box() {}

    Box(int h=2, int w=3, int d=4) {
        height=h;
        width=w;
        depth=d;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Box b;
    return 0;
}
```

This code generates `error: call of overloaded 'Box()' is ambiguous` and the build fails.

*Case 6.* As I've said before, a class cannot have two constructors of the same signature. So, the code will fail to build. The following code will not compile correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box {
    public:
    int height, width, depth;
    Box(int h, int w, int d) {
        height=h;
        width=w;
        depth=d;
    }

    Box(int h=2, int w=3, int d=4) {
        height=h;
        width=w;
        depth=d;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Box b;
    return 0;
}
```

The following error message will be generated `error: 'Box::Box(int, int, int)' cannot be overloaded`

*Case 7*. You can not have two constructors with the same signature. If you have a default constructor and a non-default constructor with default parameters and try to create an object without passing any parameters, you will get an **ambiguous call to an overloaded constructor** error like in the case 5.

*Case 8.* Your assumption is correct

The same rules apply when you are trying to create an array of objects. If you are trying to make an array of class `Box` which has no default constructor, you can do that like the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box {
    public:
    int height, width, depth;

    Box(int h, int w, int d) {
        height=h;
        width=w;
        depth=d;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Box box(1,3,2);
    Box b[5] = box;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cout << b[i].height << ' ' << b[i].width << ' ' << b[i].depth << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, you're probably better off using vectors for this purpose anyways...